# Devise: Capitalize First Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I added a new field in devise called firstname, and I want it to be capitalized by devise during registration.

I first ran:
`rails generate migration add_username_to_users firstname:string`

then

`rake db:migrate`

After that I added firstname to the `configure_permitted_parameters` in the application_controller.rb and updated the views. I basically used [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) but stripped out some unnecessary stuff.

I dont know where I should put the code for capitalizing the firstname and lastname (as well as some other validating). Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should put capitalization of first and last names in your `User` model. Every time a user is saved, you can capitalize the first and last name. In addition, all validation (or attribute pre-processing/sanitization) can be done at the model level as well.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :capitalize_names

  def capitalize_names
    self.firstname = firstname.camelcase
    self.lastname = lastname.camelcase
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**before_create**

`Joe Kennedy`'s answer is correct - you should use the [`before_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) ActiveRecord callback

The difference here is that Devise doesn't do anything with your actual data modelling - it basically just creates a series of controllers to handle the user `registration` & `login` processes

--

If you want to ensure certain attributes of your `User` model are saved in a particular style, you'll be best setting it in the model itself:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_firstname

   private

   def set_firstname
      self.firstname.titeize
   end
end
```

This should allow you to set the attribute to have the first letters of each word capitalized

--

**System**

An alternative would be to look at your system

*Why* are you insisting the data be stored this way? It seems very inefficient to save all your data in the same for the sake of styling.

I would use the CSS [`text-transform`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) function to do this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.first_name { text-transform: capitalize; }

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= content_tag :span, @user.firstname, class: "first_name" %>
```

Comment: Why use before_create instead of before_save?

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution Ever:

```
 class Role < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :capitalize_names
  def capitalize_names
    self.name.titlecase
  end
 end
```

Output will be:

```
'super admin'.titlecase
 Super Admin
```

Answer (score -1):

This should probably go in the User Controller (or whichever controller inherits from the Devise Controller and creates the new user). In the create method, before you save the user to the database, add whatever attributes you want to it (i.e. capitalizing the first letter) and then save it.

Answer (score -1):

```
def create
  User.create(email: params[:email], first_name: params[:first_name].capitalize)
end
```

Although I'd suggest you just output the capitalize in your views and not when saving.

Comment: Where should I put this? In the application_controller?

Comment: Wherever you're outputting the user's first name.